# How to get row names using Pander in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pander

I am using Pander to get my tables in R markdown, and I would like to add row names to my tables, which are not there by default. 
here is my script:

```
age.frequency.table <- xtabs(~age, data=iceland) 
pander(age.frequency.table)
```

[Here is a screenshot of the table I get on R markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvj7N.jpg)

I would like to have the row names 'age' and 'frequency'.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated! I'm very new to R/coding so apologies if this is an obvious question.

Comment: Which package is needed for the `iceland` dataset?

Comment: Hi! the dataset was provided by a tutor, and i don't think comes with any package. The packages I am using are Hmisc, psych, gmodels, dplyr, knitr, pander and g.data.

Comment: Can you please post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Without that, it's hard to help.